# How to see what ajax request is actually being submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, httprequest

I'm making ajax requests to controllers in ASP MVC 5 from JQuery. The requests are failing. However, if I put in the request by hand, for example `/Sale/fillVarietiesSelect?speciesId=2`, I get the correct response. I must be doing something wrong with my ajax request, but I can't see it. It would help me debug if I could see the actual request being made, but it doesn't show up in the URL bar (it is a GET request). Is there a way I can intercept or view the actual request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press **F12** in your browser and click on the **Network** tab. All requests being made are logged there. Click on the request you want to inspect to see all its details.

Comment: That's great! I should be thrashed for not using my developer tools better. Soooo, the request is not being made at all. I've confirmed that I'm in the function up to the point of the ajax call, but somehow the request isn't being made. So, on to the next problem...

Comment: Just FYI: You can further filter to 'XHR' tab, where you can see all Ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

I use fiddler, it's a great tool to see incoming/outgoing traffic:

http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Looks cool, but I'd like a simple solution that doesn't involve learning new software/technology.